# How to install ImageMagick for WAMP 2.5

Tags: php, imagemagick, wamp

WAMP does not come with ImageMagick PHP extension installed, how do I install it manually? All the tutorials I have found seem outdated and too confusing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got ImageMagick to work on WAMP 2.5 on Windows 8.1 . Here's what I did.

1. Download the latest ImageMagick here:
   http://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows
2. Install it here (It should be ticked by default, but make sure you tick the "Add application directory to your system path" when installing):
   C:\imagemagick
3. Go to the latest folder created and download the latest zip file from here (with x64 or x86 matching your ImageMagick install file):
   http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/
4. Extract the php_imagick.dll from that file to here:
   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\
5. Open php.ini file in text editor from here
   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\
6. Search for commented line "Windows Extensions" and under the extensions list (for me the last one is extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll) add:
   extension=php_imagick.dll

Then RESTART your computer and ImageMagick should work, it did for me at least.

Comment: if you're having trouble activating Imagemagick on Windows and installed Imagemagick 7.0, here's what worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37927537/47680.

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this in 2019, latest versions of downloads still work. Additionally, I only needed to "quit" WAMP in order to have Imagick become available after the installation steps, no computer restart required.

Comment: Note that for me only the TS (thread safe) would work. The NTS would not work.

Comment: Same here, only the TS version worked! Good to know!