# How to install ImageMagick with Wampserver 3.0.0 64?

Tags: php, imagemagick, wampserver

I lost a day trying to figure this out, at various times getting "no decode delegate for this image format" and "The specified module could not be found" errors. The information I could find on these problems was dated in terms of version numbers, and many included instructions like overwriting the ImageMagick-installed dlls from the PECL distribution or copying dlls into windows/system32; two things I didn't want to do.

Environment: Windows 10
Wampserver: 3.0.0, Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Downloaded and installed latest ImageMagick:
   `ImageMagick-7.0.2-0-Q16-x64-dll.exe`
2. Downloaded `php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-5.6-ts-vc11-x64` from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3rc1/
3. Unpacked `php_imagick.dll` into `[wampserver directory]\bin\php\php5.6.16\ext`
4. Added `extension=php_imagick.dll` to
   `[wampserver directory]\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin\php.ini`
5. Got "no decode delegate for this image format" error, but at least imagick showed up in phpinfo() where I could see that php_imagick.dll was compiled with `ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x64`. There was no obvious way to know this beforehand.
6. Downloaded `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe` from http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/ (ImageMagick has removed this package from their site).
7. Uninstalled `ImageMagick-7.0.2-0-Q16-x64`,
   installed `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-Q16-x64` to `c:\ImageMagick`,
   added `c:\ImageMagick` to PATH (in front, to avoid collision with windows convert.exe).
8. Verified everything ok with:

   ```
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->readImage([path to my jpeg]);

    $wm = new Imagick();
    $wm->readImage([path to my watermark png]);

    $image->compositeImage($wm, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 5, 5);

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image;
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I kept getting "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/ext/php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.  in Unknown on line 0" errors until I uninstalled 7.0 and installed 6.9.3 per your instructions. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of things. What has done the trick was to add at the end of active php.ini lines :

```
[ImageMagick]
extension="C:\WampDeveloper\Components\Php\ext\php_imagick\php_imagick.dll"
;imagick.locale_fix=0
;imagick.progress_monitor=0
```

Credit :
http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/installing-and-using-imagemagick-with-imagick-php-extension-php_imagick-dll-on-wamp