# Converting TIFF byte array into JPEG byte array in PHP

Tags: php, jpeg, gd, tiff

I could not find a way to convert TIFF byte array into JPEG byte array in PHP. I tried the following:

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring("49 49 2a 00 16 1d 00 00 80 3f e0 4f f0 04 16 0d II.........O....07 84 42 61 50 b8 64 36 1d 0f 88 44 62 51 38 a4 ..BaP.d6...DbQ8.56 2d 17 8c 46 63 51 b8 e4 76 3d 1f 90 48 64 52 V...FcQ..v...HdR
39 24 96 4d 27 94 4a 65 52 b9 64 b6 5d 2f 90 c0 9..M..JeR.d.....");
```

but it returns `Data is not recognized format`.

So how do I convert TIFF bytes into JPEG bytes?

Comment: How do you get the "byte array"?

Comment: i am using call wsdl SoapClient() method.

Comment: Is it a hex-encoded sequence of space-separated bytes? I wonder what the characters `II`, `M`, `JeR` mean.

Comment: i try to put binary data but it's not possible. so just it example

Comment: @Ruslan  is it possible to tiff binary image value store as jpeg image in local folder? pls help sir

Comment: i am not getting xml response. only got binary value. i will try to give you

Comment: "This option requires two parameters, "pro number" and "document type" and will return a TIFF byte array that can be converted into a jpg, jpeg, pdf, bmp, or any available image format." my document instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GD extension currently does not support loading TIFF images. You can use [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) extension instead:

```
try {
  $im = new Imagick();
  $im->readImageBlob($tiff_bytes);
  $im->setFormat('JPEG');
  file_put_contents('test.jpeg', $im->getImageBlob());
} catch (Exception $e) {
  trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

In the code above, `$tiff_bytes` is a binary string of a TIFF image.

Alternatively, you can install the [official command line tools](http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php), save the TIFF image to filesystem, and convert it to JPEG using the following command:

```
convert file.jpg file.tiff
```

There is a number of ways to execute a shell command in PHP. I prefer `exec()` for the cases when I do not need much of control over the execution, and `proc_open()` when I need full control over the contents of the file descriptors, i.e. in most cases.

Comment: I try to use above code but i am getting error:-   Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found. i have also registered php_imagick.dll file in php.ini

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, the extension is not loaded for some reason. Have a look at the output of `phpinfo();`, if you are running a Web SAPI, or at the output of `php -m` (list of loaded modules) in CLI. Have you [installed](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php) the PECL extension? Is the library present in the extensions directory (`extension_dir` in _php.ini_)?

Comment: You need to instal Imagick module if it isn't already installed. Once installed, restart PHP and it'll exist :)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick is the official page. If you are on Windows, download the DLL into the `extension_dir`, restart the Web server, and check the output of `<?php phpinfo();`. You may find [this](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php) page useful

Comment: i try to download and put on "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext" directory and add php.ini file extension_dir but i got soapcall error. i also use soapcall function

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, there are many posts on this issue on SO, examples: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336327/how-to-install-imagemagick-for-wamp-2-5), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336327/how-to-install-imagemagick-for-wamp-2-5), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942523/step-by-step-instructions-for-installing-imagemagick-on-wamp?rq=1). By the way, Windows is not very good OS for PHP, IMO, and I doubt that a single foolproof solution even exists for this OS.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov:- I try above code i got error "NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `' @ error\/blob.c\/BlobToImage\/355"

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, could you upload the blob data somewhere and give me the link? You can save the blob data as `file_put_contents('blob.data', $blob);`. The simplest way to run the shell command is `exec("convert input.tiff output.jpg");`. Note, `convert` (or maybe `convert.exe` on Windows) executable must be available in the PATH environment variable. Otherwise, you need to provide absolute path to it, e.g. `exec("/usr/bin/convert in.tiff out.jpg");` on Unix-like OS, and something like `exec("C:\\Program Files\\Path-to-Imagick\\convert.exe in.tiff out.jpg");`.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, it is slightly off-topic, but I recommend you to work on a Unix-like system, as Windows is not appropriate OS for Web development and even for software development unless the task is Windows-specific, IMO.